# Does the Law Of Excluded Middle Apply to the Principle Of Identity and Non Contradiction?

Tags: logic, aristotle, deduction, identity

This argument will seem confusing, precisely because it observes the laws of identity being subject to equivocation. If this is kept in mind, the following should make more sense and explain why the argument leads to the following question.

The following Proposition states:

"The Principle of Identity is the Principle of Identity, or
The Principle of Non Contradiction is the Principle of Non Contradiction."

The law of identity is a proposition as it expressive both a judgement and assertion of what constitutes identity.

So is the law of non contradiction.

As propositions they are subject to the law of identity respectively.

They are not the same propositions, but both are subject to the laws of identity.

Thus the law of excluded middle requires one to be negated, thus a law being negated.

However, if one is negated then one of the indentity laws is negated.

This leads to excluded middle to be negated as well leaving only one of the laws as true.

Both P and -P are subject to the law of identity as "P=P" and "-P=-P", but one identity is false when excluded middle is applied.

The principle of identity (P), expressed as (P=P), and non contradiction (-P), expressed as (-P=-P) through the law of identity requires P=-P through (P=P)=(-P=-P).

However, non contradiction states P=/-P.

The dualism between identity and noncontradiction is premised on equality and non equality where one law it antithetical to the other.

On one hand P=P necessitates an identity through connection,on the other hand P=/-P offers a negation of identity through an absence of connection.

This connector is equivocation.

Does this mean sometimes the law of identity may be possibly untrue considering "-P", as the law of non contradiction, is subject to it?

The "equality" of identity and the "inequality" of non contradiction are respectively thetical and antithetical, as one statement cancels the other out:

P=P but P cannot equal -P, however -P=-P is necessary if -P is to have an identity.

...thus one principle of identity (P=P) does not equal another (-P=-P).

What are the results of this statement considering both laws exist according to the principle of identity but both are not eachother respectively and only one can be chosen?

To make this simple this proposition simpler the following example can be applied:

"The cat is alive and the cat is dead" is a contradiction.

(C=C)=/(-C=-C)

However if the context is changed:

"The cat is alive and the cat is dead in my memory of January" then the identity of the cat can contradict itself given a change of context.

((C=C)=(-C=-C)) = (M=J)

The law of non contradiction is over ruled, as well as excluded middle by an inherent middle proposition of (M=J)

This necessitates the law of identity as P(x)=-P(x) where x=x but x is undefined considering the law of identity is undefined.

The law of identity is undefined because excluded middle and non contraction are negated...thereby leaving the law of identity as non existent as "=" cannot be defined.

Therefore P(x)=-P(x) cannot exist except as

((P(x))(-P(x)))  where ( ) observes all axioms as fundamentally contexts or "sets" of variables.

This necessitates that only P=P as an aristotelian law is left, but that means the law exists only if it relates to itself:

(P=P)

((P=P)=(P=P))

....

Where P exists as it's own context (P)=(P) considering "=" is undefined except through P.

An example of this can be observed where "equals" as "=" can be replaced with the following meanings with corresponding signs if iPad permits:

Is

Therefore

Because

If then

Tends to

Therefore/because

Necessitates

Implies

Infers

Etc. With the "=" sign being represented through a variety of symbolic expressions (cannot copy an paste on ipad).

Thus "=" is subject to equivocation and can be replaced with the variable: P as P(P)P

Thus (=)P(=) where = is P allowing "=" to have an identity.

(P)=(P)

(=)P(=)

Therefore

((P)P)

Thus one identity is a context that is inherently void until another context occurs.

This necessitates, whether I want it or not, that the Principle of identity P=P is void and must be replaced with not a principle (as principles are void) but an assumption:

The Assumption of Inherent Void: (P)

Comment: I do not see any "fallacy" in the above sentences... and I do not see any special meaning also.

Comment: @Mauro...I never implied a fallacy or not a fallacy.  I asked does it apply and what are the results of it does?  It is a legitimate question.  The principle of identity and the principle of non contradiction can respective be observed as P and -P, thus as propositions they are subject to excluded middle.  I dont see any meaning to your statement.

Comment: I mean : I do not see any issue with the self-application of the PofI to itself. What I mean is : what does it mean to assert "The Principle of Identity is the Principle of Identity" ?

Comment: It means the Principle of Identity, as a proposition, is subject to it's own identity laws.  The same applies respectively for non contradiction as being subject to the same identity laws.

Comment: @logikal... meaningless and provides no answer.  The laws are propositions thus follow there own nature.  P=P where P is the Priniciple of Indentity is necessary but also shows that excluded middle can be applied to the laws.

Comment: I am not clear about what you are asking.

Comment: @Mark...the law of identity is a proposition.  So is the law of non contradiction.  As propositions they are subject to excluded middle, but this requires one of the propositions as a law to be negated...what happens?

Comment: A proposition is a statement or assertion which expresses a judgement or opinion, thus the principles of identity are propositions.  It is clear to me you dont have anything to contribute if you will not explain what a proposition is.

Comment: The law of identity is not the negation of the the law of non-contradiction, so the question is non-sensical.

Comment: @Conifold Perhaps that's what Eodnhoj7 is asking?

Comment: @Geremia...that is part of my point...+1.  The laws negate themselves if they are applied to themselves as they are propositions.

Comment: @Conifold: the law of non contradiction is the negation of equality.  Identity is the thesis of equality.  One proposition represents equality.  The other represents anthithetical in equality.  -P=-P must follow P=P, but this necessitates one identity as true and another false, but both follow the principle of identity.  Thus sometimes the principle of identity is true....other times it is false because both P and -P are grounded in identity.

Comment: The negation of P=P is ¬(P=P), which is rather different from ¬(P∧¬P), the [law of non-contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction). If you want to post here you should stop stringing fancy words together into random combinations and pay more attention to what they mean.

Comment: @conifold...no need to be unkind and make personal accusations... what you claim  is the same thing as saying -(P=P) = (-P=-P).  -(Pv-P) is the same as (-PvP) and we are left with meta contexts of identity.

Comment: The negation of P is - P  which is is expressed through the principle of identity as P=P and -P=-P.   However this necessitates, in the law of non contradiction that two expression of the law of identity are not equal to eachother, thus not only is the law of identity fragmented but one is left choosing between the law of identity and the law of non contradiction...thus leaving the negation of one of the laws.

Comment: You see why the question and the confusion?  Either the aristotelian identity laws are true or they are not.

Comment: "This is considering both P and -P are subject to the law of identity as P=P and -P=-P but one identity is false. " Why one of them must be false ? They are noth one the negation of the other : the negatio of P=P is -(P = P).

Comment: Its put on hold because it shows aristotelian identity properties as unclear and there is a bias towards thos dogma...the majority of the answers provided where unclear.

Comment: If you get unclear answers or comments telling you that what you write hardly makes sense, then you should ask yourself if the post really is as clear as you might think. It is your responsibility to make yourself understood beyond equivocation.

Comment: Actually the argument points out quite clearly aristotelian logic necessitates equivocation.  It is clear in pointing out aristotelian identity properties are unclear if taken to there logical conclusion.  Aristotle's laws begin with equivocation...that is what they are literally grounded in...  If I say 3 sentences, such as (P=P)=(-P=-P)

Comment: Therefore P=-P...and this necessitates a contradiction...people will accuse me of not explaining myself.  The truth is Aristotle's identity properties make no sense whatsoever if you apply the laws to the laws.

Comment: Just because a teacher teaches something and the student does not understand, it does not mean the student is dumb and the teacher knows what he is talking about.

Comment: I updated the question to explain why it will seem confusing...

Comment: Michael's answer does a decent job in telling you why your conclusions are based on a wrong usage of signs, not insight. You can reject that and reiterate the same problematic argument time and again, it does not change anything.

Comment: @Phillip...the usage of signs is subject to a context of interpretation which in itself is a problem of identity.  P can be any proposition with a proposition fundamentally meaning an assertion or assumption.  P can mean "equality is equality" as P is highly indefinite by its nature as a variable.  Equality is not defined, at all, and paradoxically can be replaced by a number of different connectors as either words or symbols.  This P(P)P can be an accurate representation considering the multitude of meaning "=" is accepted to have by philosophers.  However if P(P)P is valid, the identity...

Comment: Is subject to a recurssion of contexts where ((P)P) is valid as well as (P).  Identity is thus contextual, as the relation of one context to another by the inversion of one context into another.

Comment: The signs are assumed, thus are variables that can be inserted where P exists.

Comment: Identity is inherently void, much like an empty set.

Answer (score 3):

> The Principle of Identity is the Principle of Identity, or The
>   Principle of Non Contradiction is the Principle of Non Contradiction.

It is not right to say, of the propositions making up this disjunction, that "the law of excluded middle requires one to be negated".

I'm not exactly sure what is causing the confusion, but it seems to me that you think the law of excluded middle is the following:

> In a proposition of the form "p or q" exactly one of the disjuncts is
>   true.

That is not a logical law. Maybe you are confusing it with the similar, but (classically) true:

> In a proposition of the form "p or not-p" exactly one of the disjuncts
>   is true.

So for

> The Principle of Identity is the Principle of Identity, or The
>   Principle of Identity is not the Principle of Identity.

it is right to say that one disjunct must be false.

---

Edit:
Another guess at what is causing the confusion: You might think that the equivalence of a=a and b=b means that a=b. This might seem plausible if one confuses identity with equivalence, using the same sign for both: a=a=b=b. But the middle «=» should be a propositional connective. So the relevant form is really «a=a if and only if b=b». Cats are cats if and only if dogs are dogs. It does not follow that cats are dogs. Nothing changes if «a» and «b» stand for propositions instead of animals.

---

Second edit:
Let’s agree that «The law of identity is a proposition». It is the proposition that, for all individuals a, a is a. Let’s signify the proposition with «LI». We can also agree that the law of noncontradiction is a proposition. It is the proposition that, for all propositions p, it is not the case that both p and not-p. Let’s give it the propositional sign «NC».

You say that both propositions are subject to the law of identity. I can also grant that, but remember: The letters that flank the equality sign are names of individuals, so if we plug our propositional sign «LI» into the position of such a name, we are mentioning the proposition. LI=LI can be rendered intuitively as

> [The proposition which says that, for all individuals a, a is a] is [the proposition which says that for all individuals a, a is a].

(The brackets are only there to parse the texts for ease of reading.)

And NC=NC:

> [The proposition which says that, for all propositions p, it is not the case that both p and not-p] is [the proposition which says that, for all propositions p, it is not the case that both p and not-p].

Since both of these resulting propositions are trivially true, they are equivalent. We can express that equivalence like this: «LI=LI if and only if NC=NC», or like this «(LI=LI)<->(NC=NC)». But remember the difference between «=» and «<->». In particular, note that «(LI=LI)<->(NC=NC)» does not say the same thing as (LI=LI)=(NC=NC). Moreover, the *equivalence* does not justify the *equality*, and neither does the law of identity (LI). The proposition (LI=LI)=(NC=NC) is of the form a=b, not a=a. This is so even in the case where «a» and «b» stand for equivalent propositions.

It might be difficult to grasp the difference between the occurrence of a proposition as an individual and its occurrence as a proposition. It might help to see that the propositional connectives do not apply to individuals, even if that individual happens to be a proposition. So while «a=a» is grammatical «a=it is not the case that a» is not, because «it is not the case that …» cannot operate on «a». The negation operator does not operate on the positions that flank the equality sign. This is easy to see when "a" stands for an animal:

> [A cat] is [it is not the case that a cat].

But the point holds equally well when «a» stands for a proposition:

> [The proposition that cats are cats] is [it is not the case that the proposition that cats are cats].

I hope you see that «it is not the case that the proposition that cats are cats» is ungrammatical, and thus that "p=p" only mentions, and does not assert "p".

Comment: The principle of identity is grounded in equality.  The principle of non contradiction inequality.  Both symbols are the opposition of the other and are undefined except through P and -P which are in opposition.  One propostion, equality and the other non equality, observes one as the negation of the other, thus excluded middle necessitates one proposition as true and the other false...but this negates one of the laws in doing so.

Comment: The principle of noncontradiction says of a proposition and its negation that both cannot be true. The principle of identity says of every individual that it is identical to itself. How is one the negation of the other?

Comment: Edited question to make it clearer.  One negates the other as P must exist through P=P and -P must exist through -P=-P, but one identity cannot equal the other yet they require the same law to define them as having an identity.  One identity is true and the other is false as equality and inequality negate eachother, one law of identity is not equal to another law of identity.

Comment: If you quantify over propositions, saying that there is a proposition p that is identical with itself and a proposition not-p that also is identical with itself, you have said nothing about whether p or not-p is true. It seems to me you take the truth of p to follow from p=p, and the truth of not-p to follow from not-p=not-p. Saying that a proposition exists or is identical with itself is not asserting it (calling it true).

Comment: I edited my answer to add something that might address what you are saying here.

Comment: actually it is calling it true if the laws of identity sets the premise for what is true and false.  The laws of identity, all three of them, must follow the first identity law if they are to have identity hence be true.  If identity has no truth value, then neither to the laws presented.

Comment: @Michael...I like the edit to your answer and will +1 it (along with how respectful and patient you have been), because you did address a solid point...but it still does not solve the problem and this problem is one of isomorphism: it P=P true because of (P)=(P) or P(=)P?  It shows isomorphism, or the inversion of one state to another, as inherent within the properties.

Comment: So if P(=)P, ie "equality" is the premise we are left with and "either/or" state between the law of identity and non contradiction.  The problem is not that "a=a=b=b" but rather "(a=a)=(-a=-a) where a=-a because of the principle of identity but a=/-a because of non contradiction.  Non contradiction is not equal to the law of identity but exists through it...thus the law of identity is simultaneously true and false.

Comment: I've made one more edit in an attempt to address this. If it still is unclear why I think you are mistaken, we can discuss it in the chat. Hope it helps!

Comment: I dealt with an example like this a year ago.  The cat is alive and dead.  This is a contradiction.  A=-A.

Comment: A cannot equal -A unless the context is changed.  "The cat is alive and dead in our memory of January" changes the context to:

Comment: ((C=C)=(-C=-C))=((M=J)=T)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97989/discussion-between-michael-amundsen-and-eodnhoj7).

Comment: I would rather you edit your answer to address the statement so others can comment.

Comment: It does not address the cat in January problem nor the fact that "=" as subject to a variety of expressions in itself is subject to equivocation and hence a variable where P=P necessitates P(P)P